# AttributeError: Unknown property y for Seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I got this error even though I got my results also. Below is my Dataset

```
   State Station Code  Week  Score
   Karnataka         BIDE    18   8.32
   Karnataka         BIDD    18   8.01
   Karnataka         PUTD    18   7.62
   Karnataka         TKMD    18   7.39
  Tamil nadu         HSRD    18   8.40
  Tamil nadu         KJMD    18   8.40
  Andra pradesh      NZVD    19   8.19
  Andra pradesh      PKSD    19   8.37
  Andra pradesh      VGAF    19   8.47
  Andra pradesh      SKMI    19   7.11
  Andra pradesh      MRGA    19   7.17
   Karnataka         BIDD    19   8.21
   Karnataka         PUTD    19   8.09
   Karnataka         HSSD    19   8.11
  Andra pradesh      RJAD    20   8.25
  Andra pradesh      SKMI    20   8.33
  Andra pradesh      MRGA    20   7.26
   Karnataka         MDKD    20   6.80
   Karnataka         BIDD    20   8.45
   Karnataka         PUTD    20   7.92
   Karnataka         TKMD    20   7.74
   Karnataka         HSSD    20   8.26
```

```py
KN = Lower.loc[data['State']=='Karnataka']
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
sn.pointplot(x=KN['Week'],y=KN['Score'],hue=KN['Station Code'],data=KN,join=True,ax=ax1)
ax1.set(x="Week",y="Scores",title="Lower Score by Station Wise in KN",label='big')
```

I got what graph I needed but then it says unexpected property y and when I caps the Y then it says unexpected property x. If i caps both x and y it says unexpected property y again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set xlabel and ylabel, for that you need to use "xlabel" and "ylabel" instead of "x" and "y".

```
ax1.set(xlabel="Week",ylabel="Scores",title="Lower Score by Station Wise in KN",label='big')
```